# Add rows by groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I observe the frequencies (eff) of different characters (code) in a population at different dates (date2).

```
datas <- data.frame(date2 = rep(seq(Sys.Date() - 2, Sys.Date(), by = "day"), each = 2), 
                    date1 = Sys.Date(), 
                    code = rep(LETTERS[1:2], 3), 
                    eff = c(50, 30, 20, 10, 20, 20), 
                    total = 100)

> datas
       date2      date1 code eff total
1 2015-07-25 2015-07-27    A  50   100
2 2015-07-25 2015-07-27    B  30   100
3 2015-07-26 2015-07-27    A  20   100
4 2015-07-26 2015-07-27    B  10   100
5 2015-07-27 2015-07-27    A  20   100
6 2015-07-27 2015-07-27    B  20   100
```

For each dates2 I would like to add another code which "fill" the difference between the sum of the frequencies this day and the total population observed this day (total).

For example, this is the output I'm expecting :

```
       date2 eff      date1 total code
1 2015-07-25  50 2015-07-27   100    A
2 2015-07-25  30 2015-07-27   100    B
3 2015-07-25  20 2015-07-27   100   KO
4 2015-07-26  20 2015-07-27   100    A
5 2015-07-26  10 2015-07-27   100    B
6 2015-07-26  70 2015-07-27   100   KO
7 2015-07-27  20 2015-07-27   100    A
8 2015-07-27  20 2015-07-27   100    B
9 2015-07-27  60 2015-07-27   100   KO
```

And this is how I produced the output :

```
datas %>% 
  group_by(date2) %>% 
  summarise(eff = (sum(total) / n()) - sum(eff)) %>% 
  inner_join(datas, by = "date2") %>% 
  select(-c(eff.y, code), eff = eff.x) %>% 
  distinct %>% 
  mutate(code = "KO") %>% 
  bind_rows(datas)
```

But I don't like this solution and I would like to know if someone has a better one !

Also how would you do with 2 grouping variables (date1 & date 2 in the example bellow) ?

```
datas2 <- data.frame(date2 = c(rep(seq(Sys.Date() - 2, Sys.Date(), by = "day"), each = 2), 
                              rep(seq(Sys.Date() - 1, Sys.Date(), by = "day"), each = 2)), 
                    date1 = c(rep(Sys.Date() - 3, 6), rep(Sys.Date() - 2, 4)), 
                    code = c(rep(LETTERS[1:2], 3), rep(LETTERS[1:2], 2)), 
                    eff = c(50, 30, 20, 10, 20, 20, 10, 20, 30, 40), 
                    total = 100)
> datas2
        date2      date1 code eff total
1  2015-07-25 2015-07-24    A  50   100
2  2015-07-25 2015-07-24    B  30   100
3  2015-07-26 2015-07-24    A  20   100
4  2015-07-26 2015-07-24    B  10   100
5  2015-07-27 2015-07-24    A  20   100
6  2015-07-27 2015-07-24    B  20   100
7  2015-07-26 2015-07-25    A  10   100
8  2015-07-26 2015-07-25    B  20   100
9  2015-07-27 2015-07-25    A  30   100
10 2015-07-27 2015-07-25    B  40   100
```

Thanks for any ideas !

Comment: Using `data.table`, you can do this with `rbind` i.e. `rbind(datas,setDT(datas)[, list(eff=total[1L]-sum(eff), code='KO',total=total[1L]),.(date2,date1)])[order(date2)]`

Comment: Thanks akrun, very nice solution, data.table is beautiful and I should learn about it.. Though I was using dplyr for all the data wrangling in this project and all my objects are tbl, so i have to "unclass" usign `as.date.frame`. Am I going to have troubles if I switch types for computations with a nicer data.table solution ? (And after go back to dplyr functions, I don't have the  time to change all my code to data.table)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  It's okay.  I put that in the comments as you were looking for a dplyr only solution.   Your code looks fine, although it may be easier to convert the `data.table` command to `dplyr`.

Comment: Probably a `dplyr` equivalent code for the above data.table would be `datas %>% group_by(date2, date1) %>% summarise(eff=total[1L]-sum(eff), code='KO', total=total[1L]) %>% bind_rows(., datas) %>% arrange(date2,code)`

Comment: Thanks ! I think I will use your dplyr solution to avoid troubles with object's types. Put it as an answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
 library(dplyr)
 datas %>% 
   group_by(date2, date1) %>% 
   summarise(eff=total[1L]-sum(eff), code='KO', total=total[1L]) %>%
   bind_rows(., datas) %>%
   arrange(date2,code)
```

Or a similar `data.table` approach would be

```
 library(data.table)
 rbind(datas,setDT(datas)[, list(eff=total[1L]-sum(eff),
           code='KO',total=total[1L]),.(date2,date1)])[order(date2)]
```